# Get Texture Pixels using Rect coordinates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, getpixel

I have this one problem, I want to get the texture pixels in Unity using Rect coordinates, so something like this:

[image]

Get all the pixels from the marked area. I know that x: 0 and y: 0 is at the bottom left corner, when you're trying to get the pixels, so I tried to get the pixels with these rect coordinates:

```
Color[] pixels = texture.GetPixels(texture.width - (crop.width + crop.x), texture.height - (crop.height + crop.y), crop.width, crop.height);
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work properly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can someone give me some advice on how to solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I made a silly mistake.. Y position was alright, the only issue was the X position, which needed to be instead of

> texture.width - (crop.width + crop.x)

to just

> crop.x